# Discord.NET Have bot call its own commands

Tags: discord.net

I am maintaining an announcement bot and wanted to have the bot call its own defined slash command at a certain time. Is there any way for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just call the Method of the slash command, that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

/at a certain time/ is too vague to provide an answer to your question

Are we talking about a scheduled job executing at a pre-defined timestamp?
Are we talking about a recurring timer on a defined timed cycle?
Are we talking about an event trigger?

A command is the trigger for a defined method, so don't think of it as if you're trying to make your bot call its own command, but rather that you want your bot to perform some logic /at a certain time/. You have access to the discord client from anywhere in your application through dependency injection, so work on first getting in the context of /a certain time/, and then perform whatever logic is needed